# What are the differences in targets, and when should I switch to one?

Tags: tetris-99

So I get the 4 options for target selection are:

- Attackers
- Badges
- Randoms
- K.O.s

What I don't understand is the pros/cons for selecting each one, and what situations would make each one useful.  Things like Badges and K.O. makes no sense to start off with because nobody starts off with badges, and nobody is going to start off near death unless they are purposely trying to lose (by hard dropping int he same position). I've tried the strategy then of just sticking with Attackers, but then I all of sudden get wave after wave of garbage late into the game.

So it begs the question -- what are the differences in target choices, and how can I use that to my advantage to become a Tetris 99 champion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this [Reddit user's guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/aqgmwk/how_to_win_at_tetris_99_battle_royale_mechanics/) for a full breakdown of many of the game's mechanics, including targeting.

- **Randoms**: Default option.  Garbage Blocks will be sent to random opponents. The target is switched to a new random one once an attack by you has been sent, so really it is not a worthwhile choice.
- **K.O.s**: Garbage Blocks are sent to the player closest to death. Although it doesn't change for every line sent like Random, it will still switch relatively fast as there will often be a number of people close to death. Doesn't always guarantee you getting the kill credit either as there are many others on the same mode. It is better when used towards the end of the game.
- **Badges**: Targets the player with the highest badge count. Might be good for K.O.s, but seeing as it targets the player with the highest badge count, the other player might be very skilled and could attack you back. Again, would be best used towards the end of the game, as at the beginning the badge leader changes frequently.
- **Attackers**: Targets every player who is currently targetting you. This is the only option for sending Garbage Blocks to multiple players (attack is split). It is the best out of these four for defence, as attackers will start having to deal with the lines you send. Likely the best overall option, as it can still net you some kills, defend the best from potential attackers, and means you will have to worry less about targeting.

You can also manually target (Left stick or touch screen) but this would require a high amount of multitasking, but if you are decent enough it can be done to target a specific player (such as one flashing red).