# What does targeting "K.O.s" do?

Tags: tetris-99

I thought it targeted the player with the most KO's, but I saw a review from IGN that says it targets the person closest to being KO'd.

Which is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences in targets, and when should I switch to one?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/346833/what-are-the-differences-in-targets-and-when-should-i-switch-to-one)